# Passing javascript array through ajax with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have an array that is created in my ajax php file that looks like this

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

So I echo it with a json_encode

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

This is my ajax code

```
$.ajax(
                {
                    url: "ajaxfile.php" + "?something=" + something + "&something2=" + something2 + "&something3=" + something3,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON,
                    success: function (data) {
                        object = data;
                        functionIwantthearraytobepassedto();
                    }
                }
            )
```

In the console all I get is

> **Notice**:  Array to string conversion in
>   **ajaxfile.php** on line
>   **78**
>  "[Array]"

Where am I going wrong? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Please show the full PHP code

Comment: You have to pass your object through the functionIwantthearraytobepassedto in order to access it within the function unless it's a global variable. So in other words functionIwantthearraytobepassedto(object).... but first make sure object is even getting your data, without seeing the rest of your code we can't be much more help then that.

Comment: It is definitely getting the data initially I didn't have the json encode because I thought it would would without it. When I did that the console log showed the full array but not as an array

Comment: What is your code on line 78 in ajaxfile.php? What do you see when you access the php file directly on your browser like this: http://your-url-.com/ajaxfile.php?something=xx&something2=yy&something3=zz

Comment: I get "[Array]". On line 78 I am converting the result of the sql while loop into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add a header:

```
header('Content-Type:text/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your ajax 
`dataType: 'json'`

and

`cotentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`